# Strange And Wierd Case In Class Value C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am giving up how what is wrong with this class. I will give the example for you to figure it out what happen with this code.

First :
I have a class name : **classRequest**. The Structure is like below :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[System.Serializable]
public class classRequest {
    public int OrderNumber;
    public string RequestName;
    public int Qty1;
    public int Qty2;

  public classRequest (int ordernumber, string requestname, int qty1, int qty2) {
        OrderNumber = ordernumber;
        RequestName = requestname;
        Qty1 = qty1;
        Qty2 = qty2;
    }

    public classRequest() {

    }
}
```

Second : I have a List RequestOrderx. Here We add 5 Item inside. (This we call it Database)

```
RequestOrderx.Add (new classRequest (100,"Church Delivery",0,0));
RequestOrderx.Add (new classRequest (100,"School Order",0,0));
RequestOrderx.Add (new classRequest (100,"Lucy Special Delivery",0,0));
RequestOrderx.Add (new classRequest (100,"Bobby Wierd Order",0,0));
RequestOrderx.Add (new classRequest (100,"Bobby Special Delivery",0,0));
```

Third : I have a Variable `List<classRequest> RequestOrder = new List<classReqeust>();` Then I Generate The Value From Database To Variable `REquestOrder`.

The Code Is Like :

```
for(int j = 0; j < Player.RequestOrder.Count; j++) {
    Player.RequestOrder [j] = Database.RequestOrderx [i];
    Player.RequestOrder [j].OrderNumber = j+1;
}
```

Now List RequestOrder Contain 5 Item from database with the paramater OrderNumber change to : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Question 1 : Why When I Debug.Log(Database.RequestOrderx[0] - until [4] the paramater Database.RequestOrderx[0].OrderNumber change to = 1 and soon ?

**I Think Iam NOT change it in the RequestOrderx But I Change The OrderNumber in Variable List RequestOrder.** Why The Database Change Too. ?

NOTE That : The Database LIst Contain 5 Item named is **RequestOrderx** and The GEnerate List 5 item named is **RequestOrder**

Second Question :
And The to :
When I do this :

```
Player.RequestOrder [4] = Database.RequestOrderx[0];                
Player.RequestOrder [4].OrderNumber = 5;
```

When i do the script above What happen is :
Player.RequestOrder[4] The ordernumber becoame 5 .But So do the **Player.RequestOrder[0] the OrderNumber become 5 too.**

But we can see that the value should contain :
Database.RequestOrderx[0] CONTAIN "Church Delivery" With OrderNumber 100
Player.REquestOrder[0] CONTAIN "Church Delivery" With **Ordernumber 1.**

I don't understand what happen with this.

Comment: Unlike primitives, classes are passed by reference. By doing `Player.RequestOrder[4] = Database.RequestOrderx[0]` they are both referring to the same object. I assume that `Database.RequestOrderx[0]` is also (by reference) equal to `Player.RequestOrder[0]`. By changing the value in one of these 3 objects, all of them will have the same value, because they all represent the same object. So in your case when you do `Player.RequestOrder [4].OrderNumber = 5`, `Database.RequestOrderx[0]` and `Player.RequestOrder[0]` both become `5`.

Comment: Could You Post The Answer. How i must pass the database value to the list variable. I think this is the answer. I will tick it. Because Lastly i have ever met this problem but i am forget and to figured it out.

Comment: Instead of assigning with `Player.RequestOrder[4] = Database.RequestOrderx[0]` try `Player.RequestOrder[4] = (classRequest)Database.RequestOrderx[0].MemberwiseClone()`. But this will work only on classes that contain **primitives only**. However you should really read more about [Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx) in general.

Comment: What do you mean by work only on class that contain primitive only ?

Comment: See [7.3 Primitive Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711900(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Lastly i do like this : Player.RequestOrder[5] = new classRequest(Database.RequestOrderx[0].OrderNumber, Database.RequestOrderx[0].RequestName, Database.RequestOrderx[0].Qty1,Database.RequestOrderx[0].Qty2); Is it same with (classRequest)Database.RequestOrderx[0].MemberwiseClone()

Comment: **YES**, they would both achieve the same thing.

Comment: Ok Thanks Erik Kralj. Maybe i got the short one with your idea. Please Post the question. I will tick it for you after i am back. Thanks Very Much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Problem - Values vs. References

I condensed your question a bit:

> When I do this:
>
> ```
> Player.RequestOrder[4] = Database.RequestOrderx[0];
> Player.RequestOrder[4].OrderNumber = 5;
> ```
>
> Then `Player.RequestOrder[4].OrderNumber` becomes `5` (as expected), but so does the `Database.RequestOrderx[0].OrderNumber` as well, although it should still be `100`.

In C# (and also in many, many other programming languages) there are value types and reference types. On assignment value types get *copied*, but reference types will not. Both variables involved in the assignment will point to the *same memory location*.

There is [a great article on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76153/Six-important-NET-concepts-Stack-heap-value-types) that explains all the details. I highly suggest you read and understand it, before going on. (Apparently the Code Project article went offline a couple minutes after I posted this answer. But you can still find an [archived version of it in the WayBackMachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20161021082256/http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76153/Six-important-NET-concepts-Stack-heap-value-types).)

### Solution - Explicit Cloning

The easiest solution in your case is to give the `classRequest` class a method that creates a copy of the current `classRequest` instance:

```
public class classRequest {

    // ...

    public Clone() {
        return new classRequest(OrderNumber, RequestName, Qty1, Qty2);
    }
}
```

Every time you want to copy a `classRequest` instance from your "database" you can do so by calling this method:

```
Player.RequestOrder[4] = Database.RequestOrderx[0].Clone();
```

When you now change the order number of the order `Player.RequestOrder[4]` it will not affect the `OrderNumber` property in your database.

```
Player.RequestOrder[4].OrderNumber = 5;
Debug.Log(Player.RequestOrder[4].OrderNumber);
Debug.Log(Database.RequestOrderx[0].OrderNumber);
// Output:
// 5
// 100
```